# htaccess mod rewrite slash issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I managed to rewrite mydomain.com/file.php?id=## to this:

mydomain.com/##-Report_TITLE_OF_REPORT_HERE

by letting the .htaccess just take the ## and ignore anything that comes after it. I would like to change it to this:

mydomain.com/report-##/TITLE_OF_REPORT_HERE

However I cannot manage to wrap my head around it nor can I find any tutorial for this specific case online. The slash in the middle seems to muck everything up.

Could anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: What rewrite rule are you currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^report-(.*)/(.*)$ mydomain.com/file.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: when I try this the website appears completely stripped off formatting or anything

Comment: This is probably because the relative paths are now breaking. You can read more about this here: http://forum.modrewrite.com/viewtopic.php?p=10709#p10709

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^report-([^/]+)/ file.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```